# looping through a Hashsets and array list at once

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, hashset

I have a for loop that creates several Hashsets to store individual data

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++) {
        players.add(new HashSet<>());
    }
```

> that's for the players

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++) {
        amount.add(new ArrayList<>());
    } //this is the arraylist that stores the score
```

then another for loop to create an equal number of ArrayList to store the score

I know how to assess the individual HashSet and ArrayList I created

```
 for (HashSet<Integer> player : players) {
        player = userLottery(player);
    } // to access the individual hashSets

for (ArrayList<Integer> total : totalScore) {
        storage.add(total); 
    } // to access the individual hashSets
```

but I want to loop through the individual items at once. Is it possible to do that using advanced for loop like there is in python

Here the all the code from the method

```
public void run(int week, int number)
{
    int cost;
    
    int counter=0;
    HashSet<Integer> use1=new HashSet();
    int numberOfPlayers =number; // obtained from user
    List<HashSet<Integer>> players = new ArrayList<>(numberOfPlayers);
    
    
    List<ArrayList<Integer>> totalEarned= new ArrayList<>();
      for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++) {
        players.add(new HashSet<>());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++) {
        amount.add(new ArrayList<>());
    }
    
    for (HashSet<Integer> player : players) {
        player = userLottery(player);
    }



    System.out.println("");
    do
    {
        week--;
        counter++;
        cost=+2;
        HashSet <Integer>cd=new HashSet();
        comp=computerLottery(comp);

        System.out.println("week : "+counter);
        for (HashSet<Integer> player : players) {
            checkLottery(comp, player);
            
            totalEarned.add(earned(total));
        }
        System.out.println("");
        
        comp.clear();
    }while(week>0);
     System.out.println(earned(total));
}


I'm creating a lottery program using set. the user should be able to enter the number of weeks they would like the lottery to run. i.e if they enter 3 weeks the computer would generate a new set of random number each week to check against those of the player if they get a certain amount of the numbers right they get money. The user is also able to choose how many players
```

My main problem is keeping the total they've won. since it can be more than one player I decided to make a bunch of arraylist to house the individual score. so since for each week the players score will be different each arraylist keeps track of the score. for example if in the first week a player wins $100. there arraylist is updated to 100,then if they win $20 the arraylist 20 is added to the arraylist thereby keeping a running total.

Comment: What type of collection are players and amount?

Comment: I updated the code, players is supposed to be a Hashsets to store the individual player entry, while the amount (I changed it to totalEarned) is an array list, that's supposed to hold each individuals earnings for the game and update it if after every win

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I have seen you are using the values of both sets for different tasks. Therefore I propose to loop through both with two loops.

Could you share more of your code and what you would like to achieve?

### But I would propose with limited data is this

```java
int numberOfPlayers = 10;
ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();

//generate Players
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++) {
    players.add(new Player());
}
        
//lottery for player
for(int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++){
    Player player = players.get(i);
    player = useLottery(player);
    players.set(i, player);
}
```

and players defined as

```java
class Player{
    int score;
    //... other attributes
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what's the players.set(I,player) for

Comment: @CasperJosh ArrayList.set see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set-int-E-